# How can I create a Personal Area Network with my MacBook, my Windows 10 laptop, and my Android phone?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, mac, android, bluetooth

I have a four-year-old MacBook Air, a two-year-old PC laptop, and a new Xiaomi Android phone.

I want a personal area network (PAN) between them.

I don't need to share internet between the devices, and much of the time none of them will be online.

I have a large external hard drive connected to the Mac that I'd like to make available to the PC.

I already have a PAN working between the Mac and Android for developing React Native apps. These two are also connected by a USB cable. A friend set this up and I don't know its workings.

I seem to be running into problems getting the PC to work with either of the other devices.

I'm trying to follow various online guides and I'm getting various errors or often just no response from the devices.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with PAN technologies, go with a small WLAN. You can make your Mac act as a wireless router by telling it to do Internet Sharing from anything to Wi-Fi. Then have your Windows PC and Android phone join that network. It doesn't matter if your Mac doesn't actually have a working Internet connection to share, it'll still publish a wireless network that others can join, and it'll act as the DHCP server on that network for your convenience.

If you want a network that still works even when the Mac is down, have the Mac create a "computer to computer" network. This is Apple's name for an 802.11 "IBSS" network. Some people call these "ad hoc" networks. Once another device joins an IBSS network, the new device is just as much an owner/propagator of the network as the initiator was, so even if the Mac goes to sleep, the Windows PC and Android phone should keep the IBSS network alive. Note that your IBSS network won't have a DHCP server on it, so you'll be doing everything via self-assigned link-local 169.254.0.0 addresses.

Comment: So even though none of the devices will have Internet access I need to tell it to do "Internet Sharing"? This could be what's been confusing me as I've ignored articles that involve the internet, which is the most common use case and easier to find info about.

Comment: My PC and Android now connect to the MacBook and I've turned file sharing on, but the `smb://` address the Mac tells me to use does not work from the file explorer apps on the PC or Android device. Should I ask a new question about that?

Comment: Use smb://192.168.2.1/ (don't try to connect to smb://macname.local; Windows and Android don't support ZeroConf well enough for that to work reliably)

Comment: `smb://192.168.2.1/` doesn't work from the Android device's web browser or file browser, they both say "not found" or "can't be reached". Windows tells me "You'll need a new app to open this smb." The results are the same if I instead use the IP address shown in the Mac's Network System Preferences window.

Comment: @hippietrail I'll need to see the output of "ifconfig" on the Mac, and similar info from Windows and Android, to figure this out further. Can you ping 192.168.2.1 from Windows or Android?